# building method to convert array to string

Tags: java

I was dared to create a method to convert an array to an int without using the arrays.toString() built-in library from "Arrays". here's what I have:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class P01ArrayIntsInit {

    String arrayToString(int[] array){
        int[] n = new int[]{10,16,181,200,410,68,31,555,161,313};
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));

    }
}
```

I'm stuck at what the return condition should be.suggestions? this is part of an assignment where it isn't necessary but if I can come up with my own method to simplify things, I'll not hesitate to use it since I need to print an array several times. I know it's probably a dumb question but Return condition must be of a string type and I'm clueless as how to put it.
thank you

Comment: Convert an array to an `int` or to a `String`?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the returned string should look like?

Comment: You have already set the return type as `String` in the method declaration: `String arrayToString(int[] array)`. Now actually `return` the string in the method body.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch an array of ints to a string, actually. my bad there for not being clear. question is solved already but I appreciate all of you taking the time. good evening ladies and gentlemen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to implement [Arrays::toString](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28int%5B%5D%29), here are a few examples:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ArraysToString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {10, 16, 181, 200, 410, 68, 31, 555, 161, 313};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println(arrayToString1(array));
        System.out.println(arrayToString2(array));
        System.out.println(arrayToString3(array));
        System.out.println(arrayToString4(array));
        // [10, 16, 181, 200, 410, 68, 31, 555, 161, 313]
        // [10, 16, 181, 200, 410, 68, 31, 555, 161, 313]
        // [10, 16, 181, 200, 410, 68, 31, 555, 161, 313]
        // [10, 16, 181, 200, 410, 68, 31, 555, 161, 313]
        // [10, 16, 181, 200, 410, 68, 31, 555, 161, 313]
    }


    static String arrayToString1(int[] array) {
        StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(", ", "[", "]");
        for (int i : array) {
            stringJoiner.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        return stringJoiner.toString();
    }

    static String arrayToString2(int[] array) {
        return Arrays.stream(array)
                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));

    }

    static String arrayToString3(int[] array) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
        String separator = "";
        for (int i : array) {
            sb.append(separator);
            sb.append(Integer.toString(i));
            separator = ", ";
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    static String arrayToString4(int[] array) {
        String result = "[";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            result += array[i];
            if (i < array.length - 1) {
                result += ", ";
            }
        }
        return result + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: the methods using length and stringBuilder turned out to be what I was looking for. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own `toString` method, e.g.:

```
public String toString(int[] array){
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("[");
for(int element : array){
    builder.append(element + ",");
}
builder.replace(builder.lastIndexOf(","), builder.length(), ""); //remove last comma
builder.append("]");
return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer. No idea why you got downvoted.